# Set working directory for visual studio code for C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, working-directory

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio Code and I am trying to set the working directory so I can do "Assets/model.obj" to access a model instead of having to pass the entire `C:/users/...` path. After some research I have found that you need to do the following inside `launch.json`

```
"configurations": [{"currentDir": "${workspaceRoot}/"}],
"program": "${file}",
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

However, this does not seem to work for me. How might I set the working directory for my C++ project?

Updated configuration based on suggestions (Working only in Debug mode when pressing F5 and current file is main.cpp)

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Debug/App.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal",
    }
]
```

Comment: `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` will do what you want, I *think*, depending on where `Assets/` is located. And btw, that should be *in* the `configurations` array.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the reply! I have just tried this but it does not seem to work for me

Comment: It belongs in the array, and yes it works.I use it on literally *all* my C++ and C vscode projects.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have added it to the config array, still not working out. The assets folder is `Project/Assets/model.obj` and the `.vscode`  folder containing config is `Project/.vscode/launch.json` Did I miss something?

Comment: [What mine looks like](https://pastebin.com/BP5Jvbi8) and it does exactly what I hope it would. My startup location at launch is the project folder itself. Don't let the cmake target folder draw you attention away; it's just used to allow prebuilt Debug/Release/RelWithDebInfo, etc. builds that don't require rebuilding the world when I change build configs. The `cwd`entry is the one you care about, and where it is located.

Comment: @WhozCraig This is odd. I updated the post to show how I have set it up. Seems right and in the way you suggested. Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think what you're showing in your update qualifies as a valid launch config. It has no name, no request, etc. If you request to add a new config from the Run menu it should prepop most of the config. All that you should need to then is change the cwd (and of course the program, args, etc., as warranted).

Comment: @WhozCraig I took sometime to try and understand your approach. I managed to get it working in Debug mode but how could I update it so when I press the launch "play" button at the bottom of VSCode, it'll understand the working directory? Currently only works if im on main.cpp and press F5 to launch in Debug. I have updated the post to show my new configuration

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments mentioned:

put the same path in "cwd" in launch.json under configuration as stated in "program". Like:

```
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "(Windows) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Debug/App.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Debug/",
    "environment": [],
    "console": "externalTerminal",
}
```

]

Then copy your Assets to the build/Debug - folder. And you can run Debugging.