# Why my program can't find the file when opening .txt files?

Tags: c++, file-io, working-directory

I'm currently learning file I/O in C++.
I *can* open the file by using the full directory of the .txt file which is `C:\Users\mfkha\cmsc202\inclass\scores.txt`.
The path of the program file is `C:\Users\mfkha\cmsc202\inclass\Lesson 4.cpp`.
However, when I am using `scores.txt`, the program *can't* find the file.

Here is the source code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string fName;
    string lName;
    int score;

    // ifstream myFile("testfile.txt"); // OPTION 1
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("C:\\Users\\mfkha\\cmsc202\\inclass\\scores.txt"); // OPTION 2
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while(myFile >> fName && myFile >> lName && myFile >> score) {
            cout << fName << " " << lName << " " << score << endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "No file found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I *can't* open the file when I was using file name, I have to use full path tof the file, someone please help.

Comment: There is a concept called current working directory which is the folder that your program will look in. That folder may be the same as your executable or possibly the same as your project directory (in the case of Visual Studio Community). You will have to understand what folder your IDE will set when you run your code in the IDE. Also if you ran your code in your OS file browser the current working directory will likely be the same folder as the executable. So depending on how you run your code the location can change.

Comment: If you just try to open "foo.txt" then the file will be searched for relative to the current working directory of the program (`cwd`) - which may not be what you expect (it's usually the directory from which the program was launched, unless the program itself changes it). The `cwd` can be changed with (for example) [chdir()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html).

Comment: In your `c++` program when you open a file given the file name it will look only in the current working directory and no other folder. It will not search or anything. Also you must type the exact file extension. Your file browser may hide the extension causing you confusion.

Comment: The IDE i'm using is vscode. how can i change the cwd so that it reflects the location of the .cpp file?

Comment: @MuhammadKhan "The IDE i'm using is vscode. how can i change the cwd so that it reflects the location of the .cpp file?" - Have you considered reading the documentation? Also, you can use `chdir` in your program to change the cwd to whatever you like.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010073/set-working-directory-for-visual-studio-code-for-c-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010073/set-working-directory-for-visual-studio-code-for-c-project)

Comment: Side note: `ifstream`, and all of the Standard streams, follows the principle of [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/4581301). Part of this means any owned resources, like an opened file, is automatically closed when the file stream goes out of cope and is destroyed. You so not have to (and rarely have to in the general case) manually call `close`. Learn to use RAII. It helps you write simpler, more robust code.

Answer (score 0):

Every process has a working directory, initially set to the directory from which the executable was launched.

For instance, if the executable `g++` is run from "C:\users\bob\Desktop", the process will start with its working directory set to "C:\users\bob\Desktop".

File paths must be specified relative to this working directory, or as absolute paths from the filesystem's root directory.

For example, if Lesson4.cpp is compiled into an executable named `lesson4` in "C:\users\bob\Desktop", accessing "testfile.txt" requires the file be in the same directory as from where the executable was launched.

It is possible to change the working directory of your process using the system call "chdir()".

To access "testfile.txt" in your case, either use `chdir()` to switch to its directory or execute the resulting binary from your C++ code from the same directory as "testfile.txt".

Comment: "For example, if Lesson4.cpp is compiled into an executable named lesson4 in "C:\users\bob\Desktop", accessing "testfile.txt" requires the file to be in the same directory as the executable." - No. That's not correct. The executable may be in that directory, but if I launch it from `/tmp/` then the `cwd` will be "`/tmp/`" and not the directory of the executable file itself.

Comment: It would have been better if you can write a sample code which will do what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As @drescherjm commented,

> There is a concept called current working directory which is the folder that your program will look in. That folder may be the same as your executable or possibly the same as your project directory.

Well, I have tried your code, and I am using VSCode too. But your code works fine on my machine, therefore I think that your CWD (**C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory) is different from the directory of the program file. You can use `cd` to check the CWD. If the CWD is really different, you can probably set it by configuring the `launch.json`, see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference), as @john commented.
Another way to change the CWD is using the `chdir` function, as commented in the *comment* section. You should include the `unistd.h` or the `io.h` standard C library first. For example, you can use `chdir("C:\\Users\\mfkha\\cmsc202\\inclass");` in your program.

Comment: I've tried configuring it multiple times in launch.json even though as far as I can tell the cwd is set to C:\\Users\\mfkha\\cmsc202\\inclass already, could the compiler be an issue by any chance? I'm using mingw via msys2 instead of the msvc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very easy basic assumptions that can be made here:

- OP is using Windows
- OP is using MSVC (Visual Studio)
- OP is using an IDE (probably MSVC’s, but even if it isn’t)

Default project options in MSVC are to put your executable file in *sub*-folders of your program’s source code folder. If your project is in

`C:\Users\Muhammad\Documents\Projects\my-program\`

Then your executable will be in something like:

`C:\Users\Muhammad\Documents\Projects\my-program\bin\Release\win32\my-program.exe`
or
`C:\Users\Muhammad\Documents\Projects\my-program\bin\Debug\win32\my-program.exe`

You can change your Project settings in the IDE to put the .exe in the same folder as the source files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022

Another simple option is to just compile your program, then *copy* the input file to the same folder as the .exe file. After that you can run the program from the IDE and it will work.

###### From the Terminal

I personally find that it is worth your time to learn how to frob the compiler from the Windows Terminal. It is really easy once you get past the “how to use the terminal” bit.

If you start the **Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt** you can use the following commands:

- `cd C:\Users\Muhammad\Documents\Projects\my-program` to change to your source code directory
- `dir` to list all the files in the folder (which should include `my-program.exe` and `scores.txt`)
- `cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std=c++17 my-program.cpp` to compile your program using C++17 with all warnings
- `my-program` to run your program (assuming it compiled successfully)

I think I am in the minority about preferring the terminal over the IDE, though...

It just takes a bit more learning to get used to your development environment (that is, to become familiar with your tools and how to use them). Keep going! You’ll get there just fine!

Comment: So I am using vscode, and I ended up reinstalling the compiler im using (mingw or msys2 not sure what I’m actually supposed to call it) and vscode. Now I can get the file to open with the just name of the .txt file if I run it through the built in terminal in vscode. But when I hit the run button it still doesn’t work. Also the .exe is in the same folder as the .cpp and .txt files

Comment: Alas, your new problem sounds like a configuration issue with vscode. Chances are when you click "Run" that the _current working directory_ from which the program is being run is not the same as the .exe’s directory. You can verify this with a simple `cout << filesystem::current_path() << "\n";` at the top of `main()`.

Comment: Seems like you're right, when i put that command at the top, it prints out
"C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin"
Do you know how I can change that?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with vscode. Look through the configuration options.